# Using "accounts" in reference to failed attempts

Tags: word-usage, nouns, style

Is it idiomatic in English to use the noun "accounts" in reference to some failed attempts?

For example,

> Henry is a very quiet and passive student that even looks sleepy while
> in my class. Throughout this year I've been trying to get him involved
> in discussions, games and role-plays and I have virtually **failed on
> all those accounts**.
>
> Jenny realized she was running late. She grew increasingly nervous and
> did her best to get to the point of her destination on time. She tried
> going by bus, taking a taxi and even riding her half-broken bike, but
> she **failed on all those accounts**.

Comment: I don't think "accounts" there is a good choice. Why not "failed every single time"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is, in the US at least, an odd usage. It has nothing to do with failure. It refers to the items in a list. Phrases that might be more idiomatic

> failed in all those efforts

> failed with respect to each

> failed in all these attempts

Answer (score 2):

In British English, failed on all "COUNTS" can be synonymous with failure at every step, in every instance, when referring to a litany of fails.  It's fair to say that this can become corrupted in general use and people will use "accounts".

Comment: "On all counts" is a usage in the US as well though probably not as common as "in all respects." I could not account (pun here) for why "on all accounts" sounded so odd to me though comprehensible. I am sure you must be right that it is corrupted often enough into "on all accounts" that I said to myself something like "I've heard that, but it is weird." Nice bit of elucidation. I am upvoting your answer. .